# SQL server 2012 - Oder by Debit, Credit

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table data like this:

```
TranNo   Acc No       Bal Acc      Debit      Credit
```

```
  1         511          131                    1000
  1         521          131         200
  1         333          131                      80
  1         131          511        1000
  1         131          521                     200
  1         131          333          80
```

Is there a way to select data and order like this? I'm using SQL Server 2012. Thank you!

```
TranNo   Acc No       Bal Acc      Debit      Credit
```

```
  1         131          511        1000
  1         511          131                    1000
  1         521          131         200
  1         131          521                     200
  1         131          333          80
  1         333          131                      80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so.  I think that ordering by the least and greatest of the accounts gets the pairs that you want.  Then, additional logic gets the debit before the credit:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by (case when accno < balacc then accno else balacc end),
         (case when accno < balacc then balacc else accno end),
         (case when debit > 0 then 1 else 0 end);
```